# There is a complexType in wsdl ,How can i make a equivalent datacontract in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, complextype

this is what the wsdl look like:

```
<wsdl:types>
        <s:schema targetNamespace="http://mfisoft.ru/voip/service/soap">
        <s:complexType name="column">
            <s:all>
                <s:element name="name" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="value" type="s:string"/>
            </s:all>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="row">
            <s:complexContent>
                <s:restriction base="ns:Array">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="item" type="ns3:column" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                    <s:attribute ref="ns:arrayType" arrayType="ns3:column[]" />
                </s:restriction>
            </s:complexContent>
        </s:complexType>

        </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

where ns is  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
ans   ns3 is xmlns:ns3="http://mfisoft.ru/voip/service/soap"

I just want to know,if i write a WCF web service to simulate the web service descript by above wsdl,
How can i define the complexType?
for example,to the "column" ? is this ii's equivalent form?

```
    [DataContract]
    public class column
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name;

        [DataMember]
        public string value;
    }
```

and what about the "row" ?

thanks,wait for your answers,any help is appreciate

Answer (score 1):

try using [**`svcutil`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

```
svcutil your.wsdl
```

it will generate the interfaces and  data contracts etc